# Applications of $\{ e^{i\lambda_n t}\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ for $\lambda_n\in\mathbb C$.

Tags: reference-request, applications

The system $\{ e^{i\lambda_n t}\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ is a Riesz basis for $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$, for $\lambda_n\in\mathbb R$ and under Kadec's condition; see:

> M.I. Kadec, The exact value of the Paley-Wiener constant, Soviet Math.
>   Dokl., 5 (1964), 559-561.

This result has many application, fro example, in sampling theory of bandlimited functions. The Besicovitch almost periodic functions in $B^2$ (the Besicovitch space) have an expansion as
$$\sum a_ne^{i\lambda_n t}$$
with $\sum a_n^2$ finite and $\lambda_n$ real. Also these functions have some application (in signal theory, for example).

My question is in the title of this post. Do you know any application (in certain space) of $\{ e^{i\lambda_n t}\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ for $\lambda_n\in\mathbb C$? Answers, references (book, papers etc) are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is useful to multiply signals by $e^{-\alpha t}$ for a fixed $\alpha>0$ as this models attenuation along the signal channel. This the same as giving each $\lambda_n$ the same negative real part.

Comment: Having arbitrary $\lambda_n\in \Bbb C$ is tantamount to an arbitrary frequency-dependent attenuation/amplification of a signal.